# LUA, how to check if a value is in an array

Tags: arrays, lua

I recently started learning Lua but im struggling with something thats really simple, like in other languages I can simply use
if value is in array:
print("the value is in the array")

but in lua it doesnt seem to have a is in syntex instead uses == sign but even that is producing no correct results

```
local name = "kon"
local group_names = {"jeff","kon","luke"}

while true do
    if name == group_names then
        print("your name is in the group")
    elseif name ~= group_names then
        print("your name isnt in the group")
    end
end
```

Comment: Use [pairs or ipairs](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html) functions.